# laptop - hdd + ssd - dual boot from sad, how do they both see the hdd?

Tags: windows

I'm getting a laptop from my employer, it has an ssd and one hdd. I want to do a dual boot of windows 7 and 10, both on the ssd, and use the Hdd for my data. I just don't see how this works. can both OS's just see al the data on the hdd? or do I have to partition the hdd to...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both will be able to access the data on the hdd as long as the partitions on it are using a format both can read (NTFS, FAT32).

You will need to partition the SSD to have multiple partitions in order to be able to install both. You should be able to do this during the Windows Setup.

I'd recommend installing Windows 7 first and Windows 10 second in order to avoid any issues of the Bootloaders overriding each other.

Comment: Oke, this is exactly what I needed to know, thanks!

Comment: In that case please consider marking it as the solution and as always [Pay it forward](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) ;)